# Heroku: cannot login to my hosted app using metamask

Tags: heroku, web3js, metamask

I want to deploy my blockchain based decentralized application on heroku.

It has been deployed but when I try to login using my metamask account the account shows as null. It works on my local machine but not on heroku.

I do not want to clutter my question with code so I am sharing a link to the code

[Code that is deployed on heroku](https://github.com/deepbodra97/ethereum-sports-betting)

Comment: "I do not want to clutter my question with code so I am sharing a link to the code Code that is deployed on heroku"—in the future please don't do this. Questions here must be self-contained. We don't need all of your code, but we do need enough to understand the question. A [mcve] is ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I was documenting the code for github and realized that I did not whitelist the app url in the metamask settings.